# Make a tree view from data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have data about folders and them sub-folders. My problem is I don't know how to make nested sub-folders, for example, I have an array with folders. I got a folder 'test' which has an array of sub-folders labels and there's a folder 'daamn' and inside that 'daamn' there are other sub-folders. But that 'daamn' sub-folders not inside the second array, it's in the first array.

```js
[
  {
    "path": ".TemporaryItems",
    "label": ".TemporaryItems",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "1",
    "label": "1",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/",
    "label": "test",
    "rec": true,
    "subDirectories": [
      {
        "name": "daamn",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": false
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder (2)",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder (3)",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder (4)",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder (5)",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "test/daamn/",
    "label": "daamn",
    "rec": true,
    "subDirectories": [
      {
        "name": "anotherone",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "test/daamn/anotherone/",
    "label": "anotherone",
    "rec": true,
    "subDirectories": [
      {
        "name": "vade",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "test/daamn/anotherone/vade",
    "label": "vade",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder",
    "label": "New folder",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder (2)",
    "label": "New folder (2)",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder (3)",
    "label": "New folder (3)",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder (4)",
    "label": "New folder (4)",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder (5)",
    "label": "New folder (5)",
    "rec": false
  }
]
```

A 'rec' flag means there are other sub-folders or not.

As expected output, I need a DOM(actually just a list with `<ul>` and `<li>`). Something like this, sorry for paint [image]

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: @bird forgot to add, sry, one moment please

Comment: [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/)?

Comment: @ClydeFrog changed description

Comment: @bird just a list of <ul> and <li>

Comment: may be this could help you http://embed.plnkr.co/4H0hIL/

Comment: have you tried react-ui-tree. here is the link to a demo https://pqx.github.io/react-ui-tree/.
If your desired output is this, otherwise you can share more details.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahShafiq looks like what I was looking for but I'm not sure if an row can be a custom React component

Comment: @AlexPark i think you can by passing a function returning a custom React Element to  `renderNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use recursion to rebuild the tree, by that the sub-folder is children of the parent folder.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "path": ".TemporaryItems",
    "label": ".TemporaryItems",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "1",
    "label": "1",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/",
    "label": "test",
    "rec": true,
    "subDirectories": [
      {
        "name": "daamn",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": false
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder (2)",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder (3)",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder (4)",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      },
      {
        "name": "New folder (5)",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "test/daamn/",
    "label": "daamn",
    "rec": true,
    "subDirectories": [
      {
        "name": "anotherone",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "test/daamn/anotherone/",
    "label": "anotherone",
    "rec": true,
    "subDirectories": [
      {
        "name": "vade",
        "isDir": true,
        "isEmpty": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "test/daamn/anotherone/vade",
    "label": "vade",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder",
    "label": "New folder",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder (2)",
    "label": "New folder (2)",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder (3)",
    "label": "New folder (3)",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder (4)",
    "label": "New folder (4)",
    "rec": false
  },
  {
    "path": "test/New folder (5)",
    "label": "New folder (5)",
    "rec": false
  }
]

const folrLvl = str => str.split('/').filter(e => e !== "").length

function recursion(lvl = 1, path) {
    const rs = [] 
    const matched = arr.filter(e => 
      folrLvl(e.path) === lvl && (!path || e.path.indexOf(path) === 0))
    matched.forEach(ee => {
      const { path, rec, label } = ee
      if(!rec) rs.push(ee)
      else rs.push({path, label, rec, children: recursion(lvl + 1, path)})
    })
    return rs
}

const rs = recursion()
console.log(rs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [react-ui-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ui-tree) in which you can call `renderNode` in order to render a custom React Element.

```
<Tree
 paddingLeft={20}              // left padding for children nodes in pixels
 tree={this.state.tree}        // tree object
 onChange={this.handleChange}  // onChange(tree) tree object changed
 renderNode={this.renderNode}  // renderNode(node) return react element
/>
```